# Wso2 issue when recreating the tenant (Creating the deleted tenant). If i restart the wso2 server I am able to create tenant on wso2 as expected

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

When deleted tenant from `ql admin UI` and tried to recreate tenant below is issue:

> [2019-10-22 09:46:34,897] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm} -  nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExceptionorg.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExceptionat org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:395)at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:222)at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:127)at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:264)at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.getTenantUserRealmInternal(DefaultRealmService.java:185)at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.access$000(DefaultRealmService.java:63)at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService$1.run(DefaultRealmService.java:156)at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService$1.run(DefaultRealmService.java:153)at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.getTenantUserRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:153)at org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.core.TenantPersistor.addTenantAdminUser(TenantPersistor.java:200)at org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.core.TenantPersistor.persistTenantInUserStore(TenantPersistor.java:120)at org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.core.TenantPersistor.persistTenant(TenantPersistor.java:66)at org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.services.TenantMgtAdminService.addTenant(TenantMgtAdminService.java:75)at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:173)at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:147)at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:232)at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:72)at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:65)at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:65)at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExceptionat sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:349)... 74 moreCaused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Illegal access attempt to cache ] owned by tenant {[bowl.comde],[56]} by tenant {[bowl.comde],[57]}at org.wso2.carbon.caching.impl.Util.checkAccess(Util.java:46)at org.wso2.carbon.caching.impl.CarbonCacheManager.removeCache(CarbonCacheManager.java:163)at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.initUserCache(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:4256)at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:253)at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:122)...

Answer (score 0):

In WSO2 Identity Server, once tenants are created from the management console UI, they cannot be deleted from the management console. To delete the tenants, you can use [RemoteTenantManagerService](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-user-ws/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.stub/src/main/resources/RemoteTenantManagerService.wsdl) and restart the server.

The issue when recreating deleted tenant was caused due to a cache entry and persisted configurations that won't get removed when deleting the tenant through the admin service. Once you restart the server, the cache will be cleared. Then you can create a tenant with the same domain name.

There is a [git issue](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/4386) to track this and please refer to the issue for further information.

Comment: With Api only i deleted the tenant on wso2. So I wanted to know the solution without restarting the server.

Comment: I saw the comments on git issue and will try with wso2 latest version.